# Access static members from constructor function

Tags: typescript, types, constructor, static

I have a problem accessing static members from an instance of class constructor. The code works, but the type info is wrong.

```
var ctor: { new (...args: any[]): Foo } = undefined as any;

function decorator() {
    return function <T extends { new (...args: any[]): Foo }>(constructor: T) {
        ctor = constructor;
        return constructor;
    }
}

@decorator()
class Foo {
    static Func = () => console.log("Hi");
}

Foo.Func();
ctor.Func();
Foo.prototype.constructor.Func();
```

In the above example calling the `Foo.Func` is ok. The second call tells me that there is no `Func` member. The third option should basically be the same as the second one, but since `prototye` has is of `any` type, the type information is lost.

Is there a way to properly type the `ctor` so the static members can be seen on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tyepof Foo` to get the actual type of the class (not the instance). This will contain any static methods:

```
var ctor: typeof Foo = undefined as any;

function decorator() {
    return function <T extends typeof Foo>(constructor: T) {
        ctor = constructor;
        return constructor;
    }
}

@decorator()
class Foo {
    static Func = () => console.log("Hi");
}

Foo.Func();
ctor.Func();
```

A more generic approach that does not tie you to a specific class is to add the methods to the constructor signature:

```
interface DecoratableClass {
    new (...a: any[]) : any // replace any with an interface as needed
    Func: ()=> void
}
var ctor: DecoratableClass= undefined as any;

function decorator() {
    return function <T extends DecoratableClass>(constructor: T) {
        ctor = constructor;
        return constructor;
    }
}

@decorator()
class Foo {
    static Func = () => console.log("Hi");
}

@decorator() // error no Func
class BadFoo {
    static NoFunc = () => console.log("Hi");
}

Foo.Func();
ctor.Func();
```

Comment: This solution works fine in playground but when I implemented it in my project, all of the static members are `undefined` on the constructor instance. Any idea why that could be? Can it have something to do with the build process?

Comment: @MarošBeťko should work , do you use typescript or babel for transpilation ?

Comment: I'm using babel

Comment: Also when I `console.log` the saved ctor it logs a `Descriptor` object with `elements` attribute while in the playground it looks different.

Comment: @MarošBeťko not sure about how decorators are invoked in babel. I believe the order of invocation is different

Comment: Ok so replacing the `decoratorsBeforeExport` with `legacy` in `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` seems to have fixed the issue.